# How to get translated category name in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I have this module that doesn't translate category name, so I thought to modify it but I don't know how Prestashop gets the translated name.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

In PrestaShop if you have multiple languages
Then you can add name in all languages by selecting language drop down at right corner of name text field .

Once you added name in each language then when you visit front end and choose language it will display corresponding name to selected language in fronted which you have entered in back office for that language

Answer (score 1):

I added second language translation from the drop down but the category is not translated in that module, so I wanted to modify it maybe changing the query but I don't know how to do it. It echos $category.cate.name_category only in one language.
[image: Here the screenshot]